# Crontab -e @reboot script doesn't start on restart

Tags: cron

I add a string to crontab -e

```
@reboot /home/user/start-ethminer.sh > /home/user/start-ethminer.log 2>&1
```

My `/home/user/start-ethminer.sh` file has the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -m -d -S eth /usr/bin/ethminer -G -F http://some_pool_address_here
```

but it never starts on reboot, however if i run /home/user/start-ethminer.sh i don't see any issues

Comment: Since there is nothing special in that `start-ethminer.sh` file you might just need to run  `screen -m -d -S eth /usr/bin/ethminer -G -F http://some_pool_address_here >/home/user/start-ethminer.log 2>&1`.  Later connect to it using `screen -r eth`.

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted? Is the file `/home/user/start-ethminer.log` created?